# Expression string builder QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I created a virtual field in my layer where I want a specific value to be calculated. In my attribute table I have several columns. The expression I am trying to create is the following. I want to iterate through all features and add all values of the `column age` who have a specific value, let's say the name of the features should be marc. In my first attempt I created this:

```
CASE WHEN  "name"  = "marc" THEN  sum(  "age" ) END
```

But it kinda doesn't work and I don't know how to iterate though all features in the layer and only choose those features with the name marc. Any advice?

Comment: Change the double quote "mark" to singe quote 'mark'. Beside is it mark in K or marc in c as in your question.

Comment: @ahmadhanb - If you do that and there is at least one value of `mark` in the field, you will sum the entire field including those features which do not have `mark` :)

Comment: @Joseph I see, I did not notice that. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
sum( "age", "name", "name" = 'marc' )
```

---

Where:

- `"age"` is the field used to calculate the sum;
- `"name"` is the field used to group the different names together;
- `"name" = 'marc'` is the expression used to filter all names in the `name` field which equal `marc`.

Comment: It's better to update your answer to use 'marc' in 'c' since the asker modified his question.

Comment: In the expression builder I can see the right output, but when I try to get the value from my python script I always get `None`. Any ideas? Or should I post another question about this?

Comment: @Blinxen - I think you should post another question and include the script you used otherwise it is difficult to tell where the problem is :)

Comment: I created a new question and posted it.