# Get value, made with expression builder, with python script

Tags: pyqgis

I am trying to get a value created with the expression builder. The expression is in a `virtual field`. The expression works but when I try to get the value from my python script, it always returns `None`. Because my python script is a `custom form` I automatically get the right layer object. This is how I am trying to get the calculated value.

```
for f in layer.getFeatures():
        print(f["exprAge"])
```

Maybe I should say that the features are created with the `add feature tool` and after I identify a feature with the `identify tool` the script will run.

---

I figured out that, because my layer is a shapefile, I can't access the value. Only `QGIS` can see `virtual fields`, for other layers  those fields don't exist.

How can I get the value of a `virtual field` or can I directly "send" the value to another `non-virtual field` in QGIS?

Comment: Can you see the values in the virtual field from the _Attribute Table_?

Comment: No, but in the preview from the expression builder.

Comment: Hmm it could be a bug. Which QGIS version are you using? I tested this on QGIS 2.18.13 but I also receive NULL values when using the `sum` aggregate function for a virtual field. There was a [bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15930) issued a while ago which was supposedly fixed in 2.18.10...

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.18.14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264539/expression-string-builder-qgis), you could use a workaround like the following which either creates or updates your virtual field using the calculated sum (i.e. essentially like using the *Field Calculator*):

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

layer = iface.activeLayer()
exp = QgsExpression('\"name\" = \'marc\'')
request = QgsFeatureRequest(exp)
features = layer.getFeatures(request)
total = 0
for feat in features:
    total += feat['age']

expression = 'CASE WHEN \"name\" = \'marc\' THEN ' + str(total) + ' END'
idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('exprAge')
if idx == -1:
    layer.addExpressionField( expression, QgsField('exprAge', QVariant.Int) )
else:
    layer.updateExpressionField( idx, expression)
```

Comment: @Blinxen - Most welcome, glad I helped =)